# solve the determinent using python

Tags: python

As a simple example, let's say you have this matrix:

M = [omega 1;
     2     omega];

and you need to solve for the values of omega that satisfy the condition det M = 0. How do you do this in python?

Answer (score 3):

Use `sympy` library.

You can [create](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/tutorial.html#linear-algebra) the Matrix.
Then [calculate](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.matrices.Matrix.det) the determinant. 
And then [solve](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/solvers/solvers.html#algebraic-equations) the equation against `omega`.